# How to change the back button title react-navigation

Tags: react-native

Hi how can I change the label of the back button in react-navigation ? I've tried `headerBackTitle: 'Retour'` but it still render me `Back`.

```
UserProfil: {
    screen: UserProfil,
    navigationOptions: (navigation) => ({
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#780141'
      },
      headerBackTitle: 'Retour'
    }),
  },
},
  navigationOptions={
      headerMode:'float',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just

```
UserProfil: {
    screen: UserProfil,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#780141'
      },
      headerBackTitle: 'Retour'
    },
  },
```

}